Hierarchy filtering using SQL
I have 3 example tables in my database as below:
(1) Org Chart
(2) User
(3) Invoice
I would like to use SQL to write a view that has dynamic filtering features based on hierarchy. For example, If I am the user "Jack", who is the manager of IT department, when I execute the view, I should only see the invoice ID of 1 and 3, since invoice ID 1 belongs to me and invoice ID 3 belongs another employee "Nicole" under my department IT. Also, I should not be able to see invoice ID 2 and 4 since these invoices do not belong to users under department IT.
Is this possible to achieve using SQL in any of relational database? If so, please also provide SQL statements that can achieve it. Thank you.




Could be Section in the Team column? What behavior should be if Polla execute the view?

Yes, section could also be in the Team column. If an employee’s Team is a section, it means this employee is the manager of the section. If Polla executes the view, she should only see the invoice belonging to her (and all invoices in Purchasing Unit if any).

I hope this helps you:
WITH 
a AS 
(SELECT team FROM user
WHERE user_id=1),

b AS (
SELECT DISTINCT department as team, department as sub_team
FROM org
UNION
SELECT DISTINCT department as team, section as sub_team
FROM org
UNION
SELECT DISTINCT department as team, unit as sub_team
FROM org
UNION
SELECT DISTINCT section as team, section as sub_team
FROM org
UNION
SELECT DISTINCT section as team, unit as sub_team
FROM org
UNION
SELECT DISTINCT unit as team, unit as sub_team
FROM org),

c AS (
SELECT b.sub_team FROM a, b
WHERE a.team=b.team
),

d AS (
SELECT user_id FROM user, c
WHERE user.team=c.sub_team
)

SELECT invoice_id FROM invoice, d
WHERE invoice.user_id = d.user_id;

There may be a more elegant solution, but this one works.

Thank you for this query and it does work! A further question about a different case, if I want the filtering to be as following:
For example I am Polla, when I run the query, even if my "Team" in "User" table is "Purchasing", I should only see the invoice belonging to me (invoice id 2 and 4), but not any other invoices from any other users in "Purchasing", how should we modify the query to achieve this?

@ryan9025 What should be the result if we run the query for Jack? What is the result for Nicole?

In this different case: For Jack, result should return again invoice 1 and 3. For Nicole, result should return again 1. I can also further illustrate, so let's say we add a new invoice (5, 800, 4) as (invoice_id, amount, user_id), and also a new user (4, "Chris", "Purchasing"), then when Polla runs the query, it should return only her invoice id 2 and 4, and do not return invoice id 5 (since invoice id 5 belongs to Chris).

@ryan9025 You can use minus operator (https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/sql-minus-operator/) from our result. You need to minus all invoices of users with the same team, but with user_id != our user.

Thank you for reply. The thing is unfortunately I do not know who will be in that team in the real use case, i.e. some users will be running this query but they will not be able to modify the query on the fly. In fact, for the user_id in our current query, I will also replace it with a variable that would automatically fetch the user_id of the user running the query (our system is Google Bigquery and has such built-in variable/function). Thus, is it possible to create a view for this different case without knowing who are the users in a Team?

sorry maybe I didn’t explain well in my last comment.. in the 2nd use case I mentioned, I will create a view that it will automatically fetch the user_id when the user runs the query. Thus, I will not know who the user running the query is. Due to this, we are not able to use “minus” to eliminate other users in the same team, since we don’t know which users will be running the query. Would it be possible to modify the 1st query you’ve provided so that when Polla runs the query, she only sees her invoices and not other people’s invoices even though they are in the same team?

Hello @ryan9025 it's a bit difficult to understand the question and convey the idea of ​​the answer in the comments. Could you create a new question, and I would try to write some SKL code. There is little space in the comments and no formatting.
